# sessionStorage запись и извлечение после перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, jquery, сессия

Есть простой `input` строго без `id`, который повторяется несколько раз на странице:

`<input type="tel" name="Sender phone" placeholder="+123456789">`

Необходимо записать в `sessionStorage` значение введенного `id = $("input[name='Sender phone']").val();`. После перезагрузки страницы каждый `$("input[name='Sender phone']").attr('placeholder');` и `$("input[name='Sender phone']").val();` заполнить записанным значением.

Вот такой код написал я, но что-то не срабатывает, форма после перезагрузки становится пустой без заполненного `placeholder` и `value`

```
<script>
    id = $("input[name='Sender phone']").val();
    console.log(id);
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('telnumber') === null){
        console.log("Id default");
        element_oninput = sessionStorage.setItem('telnumber', id);
        console.log(element_oninput);
    } else {
        newid = $("input[name='Sender phone']").attr('placeholder',sessionStorage.getItem('telnumber'));
        id = $("input[name='Sender phone']").val(sessionStorage.getItem('telnumber'));
    }
</script>
```

---

*Вопрос задан заново, так как в предыдушей версии совсем не о том, что надо спросил*

Answer (score 0):

В общем, сделал вот так:

```
    $("input[name='Sender phone']").keyup(function(){
        element_oninput = sessionStorage.setItem('telnumber', $("input[name='Sender phone']").val());
    });
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('telnumber') !== null){
        $("input[name='Sender phone']").val(sessionStorage.getItem('telnumber'));
        $("input[name='Sender phone']").attr('placeholder',sessionStorage.getItem('telnumber'));
    }
```